# How to convert String to NSUUID in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsuuid

I am developing iOS Swift.

I have convert the `NSUUID` to `String` like the following:

```
var bdAddr: NSUUID?
var text: String = bdAddr!.UUIDString
```

But how to convert `String` to `NSUUID` in Swift?

Comment: ⌘-click on `NSUUID` to find out which initializers the class got.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at [Apple's NSUUID documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/) You'll see a method `-initWithUUIDString:` that initializes the NSUUID object with the string representation of a UUID.