# UUID from string always nil

Tags: ios, swift

I try to parse UUID from string but it's always nil.
I write it like this.

```
UUID(uuidString: "my UUID")
```

I even try it like this in xcode expression watcher but it's also nil

```
UUID(uuidString: UUID().uuidString)
```

But when I try NSUUID on the same string, It's working fine.

```
NSUUID(uuidString: "my UUID")
```

Did anyone know what should I check? or is there anyway to convert from NSUUID to UUID?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you check this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142278/how-to-convert-string-to-nsuuid-in-swift

Comment: If you are creating a `UUID` from a string, it must be a valid `UUID`.

Comment: @DhavalRaval I want a result as UUID. NSUUID can be initial just fine.

Comment: @Sulthan Sorry to make you confuse with "my UUID" it was just a sample. the real value was already in format that I think it's valid ("68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067")

Comment: this code is working in my project.. isn't it? 
let str : String = UUID().uuidString
        print(str)
        
        let UUIDString = UUID(uuidString: str)
        print("UUIDString print : \(String(describing: UUIDString))")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I try to parse UUID from string but it's always nil. I write it like this.*

```
UUID(uuidString: "my UUID") ->
```

[reason](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid/1411662-init)

> The standard format for UUIDs represented in ASCII is a string punctuated by hyphens, for example 68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067.
>
> Returns `nil` for invalid strings.

*I even try it like this in Xcode expression watcher but it's also nil*

```
UUID(uuidString: UUID().uuidString) -> it is returning a UUID like (7AFD7082-7A14-44F8-B839-5C4D98842798), working fine
```

Comment: Sorry to make you confuse with "my UUID" it was just a sample.

the real value was already in format like your example ("68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067").

I don't understand that is there any other condition to make it nil.

Comment: @LLF if your UUID is in correct format then it never return nil.  kindly add your UUID here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just found that it just show as nil in "XCode expression watcher". But somehow it has a value when I do a print(......) instead.

Thank you very much